# SharePoint Issue: Please let us know why you need access

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Few users find `Please let us know why you need access` but for other users its working fine.

And here is in log:

> Claims Windows Sign-In: Sending 401 for request 'http://server/Pages/Home.aspx' because the user is not authenticated and resource requires authentication.6c067b9d-8d56-3002-3b48-6aae0423fe90

How to fix this issue?

Comment: I believe the co relation id is `6c067b9d-8d56-3002-3b48-6aae0423fe90`. Search this in your SP log files and you will get the exact issue.

Comment: These are the logs:Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=False, UserIdentityName=, ClaimsCount=0. Claims Windows Sign-In: Sending 401 for request 'http://server/Pages/Home.aspx' because the user is not authenticated and resource requires authentication. Any suggestion?

Comment: What type of authentication your SP uses?

Comment: Claim-based authentication

Answer (score 2):

As per this thread [microsoft social technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/projectserver/en-US/56a3aaae-14c5-40dd-b87b-23c046f75980/sharepoint-2013-random-authentication-issue-where-users-are-suddenly-anonymous?forum=sharepointadmin)

> Microsoft Support Engineer confirmed this was a 'known issue' with the Distributed Cache and the fix is incorporated in the December 2014 Cumulative Update for SharePoint